# verify the text of the header in Protractor

Tags: protractor

The header of my page is Inventory signal
HTML `<strong _ngcontent-c1="">Inventory signal</strong>`

In order to verify the header I used:   `element(by.cssContainingText('strong', 'Inventory signal'));` 
This is not checking anything, because if I change the string for instance to Inven11tory sinal11, the test also passes.
So, I am trying to use XPath: `element(by.xpath('//strong[contains(.,'Inventory signal')]'));` , but there is a syntax error, the IDE shows it is missing a ',', but I am not able to see where, or what is the error on this line.
Does anyone have a better idea of how to verify the text of the header?

Comment: Can you post a bit more HTML? You could probably use nth child navigation from a higher element div to find the element. Please don't use xpath.

Comment: Can you actually post a snippet of the test so we can see the assertion? `by.cssContainingText()` will only return the element that matches. You have to then call something like `element.isDisplayed()` to verify the element was actually found. You could use `element.getText()` to get the text of the element but that would be redundant since you are already using by.cssContainingText to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath as below and give a try.

```
element(by.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Inventory signal')]"));
```

For element presence, use as below

```
expect(element(by.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Inventory signal')]")).isPresent()).toBe(true)
```

Comment: I used the same line you suggested, but I got a false positive, E.g, I changed the string to Inventory sign55l and the test passed

Comment: Are you checking for element presence? If so include isPresent().toBe(true). For eg. expect(element(by.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Inventory signal')]")).isPresent()).toBe(true). Edited this in answer as well

Comment: Yes I tried  expect(element(by.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Inventory si**5gnal')]")).isPresent()).toBe(true);        I changed the string, but still the test passed

Comment: Strange! Can you try with equal condition. expect(element(by.xpath("//strong[text()='Inventory si**5gnal']")).isPresent()).toBe(true);

Comment: Cool :), you can go through jasmine documentation as we need to use toBe(true) for toBe(false) for isPresent, isSelected, isVisible for any of predefined driver functions. Please give a thumbs up for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

containing text 'Inventory signal'  -> //strong[contains(text(),'Inventory signal')]

containing text 'Inventory signal' exacty -> //strong[.='Inventory signal']

I would go for the second option if the expected result is exactly 'Inventory signal'

P.S.: I am not familiar with Protractor but you could also give a try by using double quotes instead of single ones..

```
element(by.xpath("//strong[.='Inventory signal']"));
```

Comment: I used the same code you suggested, but again I got a false positive. I changed the string and the test passes

Comment: Please past the html section and the used code. Plus the expected result and the actual one. Thanks